# Why am I blocked from posting on new sites?

Tags: support

This should actually be posted on some other sites (biology meta, meta.SE, English meta and so on) but I am not allowed to do that, hence I posted it in one of the few sites where I am actually allowed to post.

If some moderator could move this post to meta.SE it would be great.

I am member on 23 SE-sites, and out of those 23 I have more than 1 in reputation on seven sites. However, since a week or so, if I sign up for a new SE-site (such as biology) and try to post a question I am prevented from doing that "because of excessive spam from my network".

I am using TOR to connect and until recently it worked fine, from time to time I had to change circuit but doing that always solved all problem (as you can see from my history). This time is different, I have tried plenty of times to get a new TOR identity or circuit but I keep seeing the same error message when I want to post on sites where my reputation is 1.

How do I get around this?

Comment: Approximately 90% of the IP addresses you connected from in the past week are currently blocked for spam. I don't have any advice except keep trying another circuit?

Comment: Besides of Tor, probably you should try VPN - but quality of VPN networks may vary depending on country where you're living in.

Comment: @SamuelLiew I would understand the blocking if I tried to sign up for a new account but now I have a reasonably credible history of non-spamming on a handful of SE sites - why is that not taken into consideration when I join a new SE site? The only reason my account would start spamming would be that it was hacked, and that risk is completely unrelated to TOR and could happen to anyone.

Comment: You can't get your new accounts instantly recognised as a "valuable user" on other sites just because your account is in good standing here. You will have to connect to an unblocked IP address to start contributing good content, which will elevate your new account out of the IP spam check.

Comment: The problem's not you, the problem is the way you're connecting: through Tor, and the IPs that are being used are spammy. Since you're coming through those spammy IPs, you are getting blocked.

Comment: @EmLi No, you *don't* have a credible history of non-spamming.  You have only a few contributions.  You'll need to have a larger history of credible contributions for your account to bypass the checks you're hitting.